# IDispatch Invoke() returns Type mismatch

Tags: c++, com, idispatch

I'm unable to successfully invoke `create_session` member. It's return `Type mismatch`

```
// COM class -> member
virtual HRESULT __stdcall create_session(
        /*[in]*/ BSTR pbszName,
        /*[in]*/ long i32Value ) = 0;
```

Trying to invoke `create_session` method as follow:

```
// test.cpp
HRESULT create_session( IDispatch *dispatch, WCHAR *member ) {
    // WCHAR *member = tlib_help::s2ws( "create_session" );
    DISPID dispid = -1;
    HRESULT hr = dispatch->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL, &member, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid );
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        DISPPARAMS *dispparams = new DISPPARAMS( );
        dispparams->cArgs = 2;
        dispparams->cNamedArgs = 1;
        VARIANTARG *rgvarg = new VARIANTARG[dispparams->cArgs];
        rgvarg[0].vt = VARENUM::VT_BSTR;
        rgvarg[0].bstrVal = _bstr_t( "loing_info" );
        rgvarg[1].vt = VARENUM::VT_UI4;
        rgvarg[1].lVal = 12;//i32Value;
        dispparams->rgvarg = rgvarg;
        dispparams->rgdispidNamedArgs = &dispid;
        EXCEPINFO pExcepInfo; UINT puArgErr;
        HRESULT hr;
        VARIANT pVarResult;
        hr = dispatch->Invoke(
            dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD,
            dispparams, &pVarResult, &pExcepInfo, &puArgErr
        );
        delete dispparams;
        delete[] rgvarg;
    }
    return hr;
}
```

I'm unable to figure it out, what is the reason of this error.

Comment: create_session seems to be a method defined on an IUnknown interface so it's "dual" if it also derives from IDispatch. Is it really? Why don't you just call it directly? Why using a named arg? Anyway, IDispatch parameters must be passed from last to first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/passing-parameters

Comment: this method is a member of a class. However, thanks bro, it's working. Thanks a lot.
Post it to answer. I'm newbie in com object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`IDispatch::Invoke()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-invoke) must be called with parameters in **reverse order**, as stated in the official documentation:

[Implementing IDispatch / Passing Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/passing-parameters):

> The arguments are passed in the array rgvarg[ ], with the number of
> arguments passed in cArgs. The arguments in the array should be placed
> from last to first, so rgvarg[0] has the last argument and
> rgvarg[cArgs -1] has the first argument.

Also, in your case, you don't need "named arguments", only "positional arguments". If `cNamedArgs` is 0, all of the elements of `rgvarg[ ]` represent positional arguments.

Comment: This is very valuable info! Thanks a lot.