# ActiveX Event call fails

Tags: c++, com, activex

I have an `ActiveX` application that have both commands and events. All the commands works fine. But events, that mixed `BSTR` parameters with `LONG` parameters are not called. In the same time events with only `LONG` parameters or `BSTR` parameters works fine. I can't figure out, what am I doing wrong. My application is too big to show the source code here, so I will provide only snippets with points of interest:

**.idl file:**

```
[id(1)] void onEvent1([in] LONG longParam1, [in] LONG longParam2);
[id(2)] void onEvent2([in] LONG longParam, [in] BSTR bstrParam);
```

**Calling event:**

```
virtual HRESULT Notify(DISPID dispIdMember, DISPPARAMS* params) override
{
    if (!params)
    {
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    T* pThis = static_cast<T*>(this);

    for (int iConnection = 0; iConnection < m_vec.GetSize(); ++iConnection)
    {
        pThis->Lock();
        CComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(iConnection);
        pThis->Unlock();

        if (IDispatch* pConnection = static_cast<IDispatch*>(punkConnection.p))
        {
            hr = pConnection->Invoke(dispIdMember, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, params, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT onEvent1(LONG longParam1, LONG longParam2)
{
    const UINT currentEventParamsSize{ 2 };

    CComVariant avarParams[currentEventParamsSize];

    avarParams[1] = longParam1;
    avarParams[1].vt = VT_I4;

    avarParams[0] = longParam2;
    avarParams[0].vt = VT_I4;

    DISPPARAMS params = { avarParams, NULL, currentEventParamsSize, 0 };

    return Notify(1, &params);
}

HRESULT onEvent2(LONG longParam, BSTR bstrParam)
{

    const UINT currentEventParamsSize{ 2 };

    CComVariant avarParams[currentEventParamsSize];
    avarParams[0] = longParam;
    avarParams[0].vt = VT_I4;
    avarParams[1] = bstrParam;
    avarParams[1].vt = VT_BSTR;

    DISPPARAMS params = { avarParams, NULL, currentEventParamsSize, 0 };

    return Notify(2, &params);
}
```

`onEvent1` works fine, while `onEvent2` is not called in the application that uses this component. On the test application all the rebuilds/updated are done. Could you please tell me, where is mistake?

Comment: Arguments in DISPPARAMS must be placed from last to first (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/passing-parameters). And depending on your context and your full code, it's also possible that you lose the BSTR memory somehow along the execution path. Difficult to say w/o a reproducing project.

Comment: Yes, I also found your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253592/idispatch-invoke-returns-type-mismatch, came back to answer and you have already answered :) Could you please write it as separate answer here? I'll mark it as answer

Comment: I'll vote for duplicate instead.